# How do I solve $\frac{d}{dt}x\left ( t \right )=-5x\left ( t \right )\cos\left ( t \right )$?

Tags: derivatives

How do I solve $\cfrac{d}{dt}x\left ( t \right )=-5x\left ( t \right )\cos\left ( t \right )$?

I tried with putting x on one side, a t on another and then integral of that, but doesn't work.

Comment: It does work depending on how you seperate ("bring the x over") . So show a bit more working out as there will be an error in one of your steps. Then we can quickly diagnose your issue and you can learn how to "debug" your steps.

Comment: Separation of variables is a good idea but you should write down your calculations in detail to discern any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{x}=-5\cos{t}dt,$$
$$\int\frac{dx}{x}=-5\int\cos{t}dt,$$
$$\ln{x}=C-5\sin{t},$$
$$x=e^Ce^{-5\sin{t}},$$
$$x=C_1e^{-5\sin{t}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

This a linear differential equation of 1st order:
$$x'(t)=a(t)x(t)$$
and its general solution is
\begin{align*}
x(t)=&C\mathrm e^{A(t)},\\[1ex]
\text{where}\quad&\begin{array}[t]{|l} A(t)=\displaystyle\int a(t)\,\mathrm d\mkern1mu t,\\ C\in\mathbf R.
\end{array}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve :
$$
y(t)' = -5y(t)\cdot cos(t) \overset{(*)}{\implies} \frac{y'(t)}{y(t)} = -5 cos(t)
$$
(*) Assuming $y(t) \neq 0$

Now integrating and remembering that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x)) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ we get :
$$
\ln(y(t)) = -5sin(t) + C \implies y(t) = \exp(-5sin(x) + C) = \exp(-5sin(x)) \cdot \exp(C) = \\
\exp(-5sin(x)) \cdot K 
$$

We also need to check if the case we ignored at $(*)$ is a solution or not. It is the case, namely $y(t) = 0$ works. So this allows $K$ to be $0$.